# Get Product Attributes to populate JWPLAYER playlist in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, collection, product-attribute

HELLO I am trying to create a foreach loop which will cycle through a given list of magento products to get their attributes in order to populate a JW Player playlist. The structure of JW Player's syntax allows for the inclusion of multiple product attributes values to build a playlist, however I need to break into the foreach when it reaches the final item in order to close the playlist config.

When not being dynamically generated, the JW Player syntax looks so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer('media1').setup({
'flashplayer': 'mediaappearance/jwplayer.flash.swf',
'width': '700',
'height': '400',
playlist: [{
    file: 'video for magento product 1',
    image: 'image for magento product 1',
    title: 'name for magento product 1',
    description: 'description for magento product 1'                                                                    
},{
    file: 'video for magento product 2',
    image: 'image for magento product 2',
    title: 'name for magento product 2',
    description: 'description for magento product 2'                                

}]                                              
  });
</script>
```

With this products collection, I want to get attributes for each product to populate the playlist:

```
<div id="tab-one" class="tabset_content">
<?php
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$product_file =  $item->getMediaUrl();              
$product_name =  $item->getName();
$product_img = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113);
$product_description = Mage::helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($product, $product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description');                
?>


<?php foreach ( $productCollection as $_product ) : ?> 

<div class="casestudies">
        <div class="jwbox" style="cursor: pointer;">                    
        <div class="jwbox_hidden">
                        <div class="jwbox_content">
                            <div id='media1'></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jwplayer('media1').setup({
                                'flashplayer': 'mediaappearance/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                                'width': '700',
                                'height': '400',
                                <?php
                                $playlist = array();
                                foreach($productCollection as $_product) {
                                $playlist = array();
                                $playlist[] = array(
                                            'file' => $product_file ,
                                            'title' => $product_name,
                                            'image' => $product_img,
                                            'description' => $product_description
                                     );
                                 echo json_encode($playlist);
                                }
                                ?>                                          
                              });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>                                                                  
            </div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the foreach loop show only 1 product attributes. I want it show for all products in the array $productCollection . Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<div id="tab-one" class="tabset_content">
<?php
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

?>


<?php foreach ( $productCollection as $_product ) : ?> 
<?php 
$product_file =  $_product->getMediaUrl();              
$product_name =  $_product->getName();
$product_img = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113);
$product_description = Mage::helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute(_product,
$product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description');      
?>
<div class="casestudies">
        <div class="jwbox" style="cursor: pointer;">                    
        <div class="jwbox_hidden">
                        <div class="jwbox_content">
                            <div id='media1'></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jwplayer('media1').setup({
                                'flashplayer': 'mediaappearance/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                                'width': '700',
                                'height': '400',
                                <?php


                                $playlist = array(
                                            'file' => $product_file ,
                                            'title' => $product_name,
                                            'image' => $product_img,
                                            'description' => $product_description
                                     );
                                 echo json_encode($playlist);

                                ?>                                          
                              });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>                                                                  
            </div>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hello Mbalparda, thanks for your help. When I use your solution, the loop dont return data so it show nothing in the player. I think there is a problem with the array variable. With my former trying the loop show only one product instead all in the collection.

Comment: You lack of basic knoledge in PHP and in Magento, the error you were having was that the vars were created before the foreach and not inside it.

Comment: Hi Mbalparda, I am not a PHP Programmer nor a Magento specialist, I am learning how to modify my site. Help please

Comment: Hi Mbalparda, I try again, your solution works very well!!! Thank you for help